# google analytics real-time API per second page views

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'd like to make a query to the google analytics real-time API that returns  page views per second for the last 60 seconds, so I can recreate a chart similar to that on the GA real-time overview page.

This is easy to do for the per minute chart using metrics='rt:pageViews' and dimensions='rt:minutesAgo', however there's no rt:secondsAgo dimension available. Is there another way of accessing this data?